# Recover from idle in transaction with postgresql and BasicDataSource

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-commons-dbcp

I run postgresql with a transactional application where the stack is:
postgresql
tomcat
hibernate/spring

This is a production application where we have a bunch of customers connected at once.  Each customer has it's own postgresql database but each customer also has many users.

Occasionally, i will get a situation where one of the customer databases locks up and I see idle in transaction tied to the processes for this customer.
 postgres: customer1 customer1 127.0.0.1(59738) **idle in transaction**

When the database locks up the other databases continue to work fine.  I can not get this to unlock without restarting the server application.

The problem is often triggered by various long running reports that the customer runs.  I believe it is a locking/blocking issue where other users are also accessing the same data in the customer database.

This problem happens rarely and I can't ever reproduce it.  But when it does happen it is a serious issue.  Mostly I just want to recover from it.

Postgresql seems to function fine itself when this occurs.  Like I can perform psql to the database and run queries.  So, I think the problem or rather the solution centers around the data source.

I use the apache commons BasicDataSource.

```
<bean id="customer1DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/customer1"/>
    <property name="username" value="customer1"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

So does anyone know of a setting in the basic data source that will kill these idle in transaction connections, throw an exception or allow them to recover somehow?

Comment: I'd start with making sure you're logging and removing abandoned connections.  Take a look at the DBCP docs (and make sure you're looking at the version 1 docs) to see how to configure this.  This **might** show an issue with connections that are left ove.

Comment: I would also suggest it may be worthwhile having a different Tomcat instance for each customer

Comment: If the reports are "long running" on the java side (ie: all data has been loaded and tomcat is struggling to render some huge pdf or excel in memory), this might be just normal: you should check in your architecture but oftentimes it is the case that transactions are committed/rolled back (and connections released to the pool) only when the request finishes (eg: open-session-in-view)

Comment: The connections never recover when this occurs.

Comment: I have been looking at the DBCP docs but I am unclear what relates to "idle in transaction" hence I am asking for help.  It also appears like the abandoned connection implementation has been deprecated so I don't know where that leaves me.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?